# in express how to execute a function (like db commit) only after successful response is sent?

Tags: postgresql, express, transactions, router, commit

#### Setup

I have a Express server in typescript
and i am using PostgreSQL as database with the package `pg` to handle db query

#### Goal

I want keep any request in a single transaction

I can execute `BEGIN;` at the start of any request.

But after the request ends I want to execute `COMMIT;`.

If something failed I want to execute `ROLLBACK;`.

Also `COMMIT;` will be executed only for POST, PUT or DELETE requests.

What would be the best approach to implemented these ?

#### Progress

I have added a middleware that can initiate a db transaction i.e. executing `BEGIN;`.

Added a middleware that would set the db client object in request object. So it (db) can be accessed in any router.

Also added a error handler that would handle any error and execute `ROLLBACK;`

for the commit, only solution I could think is to create custom `send` and `json` function and use that instead of `res.send` and `res.json` and execute `COMMIT;` at the end of these function